# Raw FTP Download File from Passive Server C#

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, socketexception

I have to get a file from the ftp server, but I'm having some specific trouble.  The general idea of the code is that I have to log in three times, and then I get a list of the files from the server.  The comes through fine, but when I go for the two files I need I get a SocketException: "An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine"

To be clear, the first file doesn't generate this exception, but it doesn't download anything, either.  The second one fails entirely.

Code is as follows:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IPHostEntry dns = Dns.GetHostEntry("SERVER");

        IPEndPoint serverIP = new IPEndPoint(dns.AddressList[0], 21);

        Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);


        sock.Connect(serverIP);

        FTPRequest("USER firstusername\n", sock);
        FTPRequest("PASS firstpass\n", sock);
        FTPRequest("USER secondusername\n", sock);
        FTPRequest("PASS secondpass\n", sock);
        FTPRequest("USER thirdusername\n", sock);
        FTPRequest("PASS thirdpass\n", sock);
        FTPRequest("TYPE A\n", sock);
        string s = FTPRequest("PASV\n", sock);
        IPEndPoint listenIP = IPEnd(s);
        Socket sock2 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        sock2.Connect(listenIP);
        FTPRequest("LIST\n", sock);


        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();


        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[25000];

            int bytes = 0;

            bytes = sock2.Receive(buffer);

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            string stringList = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytes);



            foreach (string st in stringList.Split(' ', '\n'))
            {
                if (st.Contains(".CSV"))
                    al.Add(st.Trim());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return;
        }

        sock2.Disconnect(false);

        DateTime dt = new DateTime();

        foreach (string st in al)
        {
            DateTime temp = DateTime.ParseExact(st.Split('_', '.')[4], "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            if (temp > dt)
                dt = temp;
        }

        string file1 = "";
        string file2 = "";

        foreach (string st in al)
        {
            if (st.Contains(dt.ToString("yyyyMMdd")))
            {
                if (st.Contains("CAN"))
                    file1 = st;
                else
                    file2 = st;
            }
        }

        FTPRequest("TYPE I\n", sock);

        foreach (string file in new string[] { file1, file2 })
        {
            if (file != "")
            {
                Socket sock3 = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

                FTPRequest("TYPE I\n", sock);
                sock3.Connect(IPEnd(FTPRequest("PASV\n", sock)));

                FTPRequest("RETR" + file + '\n', sock);

                try
                {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[25000];

                    int bytes = 0;

                    bytes = sock3.Receive(buffer);


                    FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(@"MYPATH" + file1, FileMode.Create);

                    while (bytes > 0)
                    {
                        writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytes);
                        bytes = sock3.Receive(buffer, 0);
                    }


                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    return;
                }
                finally
                {
                    sock3.Disconnect(false);
                }
            }
        }

        sock.Disconnect(false);
        Console.Read();

    }


    static string FTPRequest(string command, Socket sock)
    {
        string resp = string.Empty;
        Byte[] bytesReceived = new Byte[1024];
        int bytes = 0;

        Byte[] bytesSent = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(command);
        sock.Send(bytesSent, bytesSent.Length, 0);

        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        try
        {
            bytes = sock.Receive(bytesReceived, bytesReceived.Length, 0);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        return Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytesReceived, 0, bytes);
    }

    static IPEndPoint IPEnd(string pasvResponse)
    {
        string s = pasvResponse.Split(' ')[4];
        s = s.Trim();
        s = s.Trim('(', ')');
        string[] sp = s.Split(',');
        IPHostEntry dns = new IPHostEntry();
        try
        {
            dns = Dns.Resolve(string.Format("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}", sp[0], sp[1], sp[2], sp[3]));
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
        }
        int port = int.Parse(sp[4]) * 256 + int.Parse(sp[5]);
        return new IPEndPoint(dns.AddressList[0], port);
    }
```

I'm a bit new to using c# for FTP anything, so any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend just using [FtpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx) directly to fetch information from an FTP server.  It is far less likely to cause errors, as it's a very robust part of the core framework.

Comment: I would do that, but I'm not aware of a method to submit credentials repeatedly.  I am possibly wrong, however, as I am still new at this.

Comment: @SeanVDH: If it's a true FTP server, you shouldn't need to.  If it's not, I'd worry more about why the server is requiring this than how to work around it...

Comment: I was referring more to the three credentials that I have to submit.  I believe I actually have to connect through a proxy of some kind.